# javascript email validation by getting domain name

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a requirement what it meeans
if i entered email filed filled with @gmail.com, @hotmail.com,@outlook.com or @yahoo.com i need to show error like "Please Provide Your Company Email ID's And Don't Use Your Personal Mail ID's".
I want sloution in javascript language or sap ui5.
thanks in advance.

```
if (input4.toString() == "@gmail.com") {
  this.byId("email").setValueState("Error");
  this.byId("email").setValueStateText("Please enter company Emai Id");
  return false;
} else {
  this.byId("email").setValueState("None");
}
```

Comment: There are defenitly many more email domains that are NOT your company email domain, so wouldn't it be better to check if NOT(company domain)?

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the e-mail address matches your pattern using a regular expression:

```
var email = input4.toString();

if (/@(gmail|hotmail|outlook|yahoo)\.com$/i.test(email)) {
  // error
} else {
  // success
}
```

The `i` behind the expression makes it case insensitive, so that upper-case domains will also be caught.

Comment: `yahoo.com.au` is also a valid yahoo email address. I'd leave out the tld entirely